# AWS Appsync subscription filter between timestamp range

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync, graphql-subscriptions

I've an AWS AppSync API that subscribes to a `createVisitorRecord` mutation. This mutation  writes a new record to dynamodb. Th primary key is a combo of a partition key `location_id` and sort key `visit_time` where `visit_time` is a timestamp.

Here's the `VisitorRecord` that get's written to Dynamodb:

```
type VisitorRecord {
    location_id: String!
    visit_time: AWSDateTime!
    email: AWSEmail!
    name: String!
    avatar: S3Object
}
```

Is there a way to subscribe solely to the creation of new records between a timestamp range? e.g. records for a specific day between a date range? I can't find any documentation on passing arguments to subscriptions that act as filters. Any advice appreciated, or even a different approach.

Answer (score -1):

Currently AppSync doesn't support this type of filter. There is a feature request created. And the team is working on an implementation. AppSync will release an update on this feature once it's done.

Comment: If you have an affiliation there, you should enclose it in the answer!